# ubuntu command line - mkdir vs touch creating .doc file

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-server

simple question and im quite new.

how come you can create a `.doc` file using `mkdir`? whats the difference when using `touch` instead of `mkdir` to create `.doc` file?

thanks!

Comment: Can I ask what makes you think you're creating a `.doc` file with `mkdir`? You're probably just creating a directory with a `.doc` "extension." Extensions are mostly irrelevant in *nix.

Comment: The built-in way to create an empty file is `: >FileName.Ext`, which avoids the overhead of launching an external program like `touch` (and it's fewer characters to type!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a `.doc` file, or *any* file at all, with `mkdir`. When you use `mkdir`, you create a directory, as all `mkdir` "knows" how to do is creating directories.

The reason you can create a `.doc` *directory* with `mkdir` is that a dot is a perfectly fine character at any position in both file and directory names. The file "extension" is just a special meaning given to the dot in *file names only* by the OS to get a clue about the program to use to open the file. Ending a directory name in `.doc` has no special meaning whatsoever.

---

As a side note, I do not recommend creating MS Word documents with `touch` (if your `.doc` is not an MS Word document, disregard this warning). MS Word uses a proprietary format which expects even "empty" (newly created) documents to contain some data. If you try to open a binary empty `.doc` in MS Word, you'll get a nice "file format incorrect" error.

Comment: thank you so much for clearing this out! thanks also for the additional info regarding .doc files!